# apt-get can't find packages

Tags: raspbian-wheezy, apt

I've tried `sudo apt-get install htop` as per [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ps-kill-and-nice-to-manage-processes-in-linux).  It doesn't return results:
`E: Unable to locate package python-software-properties`.

I've tried `sudo apt-get update`! Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Try pinging `http://www.google.com`, `http://www.raspberrypi.org`, and `8.8.8.8` and editing with the results for each. Also, how are you connecting?

Comment: ping is fine on all of them. And I'm connecting via ssh on local network. The Rpi is definitely connected to the internet as I have used the browser over tightvncserver

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Pi. How is the Pi connected? WiFi or Ethernet?

Comment: Also, run `apt-cache search htop` then `apt-cache search python-software-properties` and post the results. As a side note, that post is Linux generic and not Raspberry Pi specific. There simply may not be a python-software-properties package for ARMv6, the ARM version the Pi is run on.

Comment: One last thing, try running `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`. This is a replacement for python-software-properties and, at least in Ubuntu (which, like Raspbian, is based off of Debian) `python-software-properties` was removed in favor of `software-properties-common` in late 2012.

Comment: Right, the Pi is connected by ethernet and the commands given yield no response (literally nothing happens), no response and `E: Unable to locate package python-software-properties`, respectively.

Comment: Okay. That means that there is no software for htop or python-software-properties in the repositories. You tried `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`?